# Create custom PowerShell Objects from multiple variable

Tags: string, powershell

This seems like this should be really straightforward but I cannot figure how to do it.

How do I create custom PowerShell Objects from multiple variable/strings?

I have 3 variables as shown below.

```
$name = @'
Bob
Kate
John
'@

$age = @'
35
12
57
'@

$gender = @'
Male
Female
Male
'@
```

How do I convert it into a PowerShell object like the following?

**Output**

```
name age gender
---- --- ------
bob  35  male  
kate 12  female
john 57  male
```

Answer (score 0):

You first split all the strings into arrays, then iterate one array by index and create variables via `new-object psobject` and `$object|add-member -type noteproperty`. Note that you'd better initially have a structure for this type of data, otherwise a missed or added CRLF can mess up your data.

```
$arrname=$name.split("`r`n")
$arrage=$age.split("`r`n")
$arrgender=$gender.split("`r`n")
foreach ($i in 0..($arrname.length-1)) {
    $ob=new-object psobject
    $ob | add-member -type noteproperty -name "Name" -value $arrname[$i]
    # add other fields similarly
    $ob
}
```

Comment: When you run your code you get **Array index expression is missing or not valid.**

Comment: Why does it add newlines between the values.

Comment: @Ishan This is how `Format-Table` works. You should not use raw output for data processing, and should you need, use `Format-List` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I'am not so proud of it, but it does the job.

```
$psobj = ($name.Split("`n")) | % {[PSCustomObject]@{name=$_}} | % {$n=0}{Add-Member -Name "age" -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $($age.Split("`n"))[$n];Add-Member -Name "gender" -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $($gender.Split("`n"))[$n];$n++;$_}
```

I create  an object just witth the name and use Add_Member to add the others members.

Comment: Why does it add ... to the PowerShell Object Output.

Comment: @Ishan I create  an object just witth the name and use Add_Member to add the others members.

Comment: @Ishan might be that your line breaks consists of `` `r`n `` rather than just `` `n ``. You can use `name=$_.Trim()` instead of `name=$_` to make sure any trailing whitespace gets removed

Answer (score 0):

This works but as stated before your data will need to be formatted perfectly.  I had to throw on the .trim() to get rid of some white spaces.

```
$name = @'
Bob
Kate
John
'@

$age = @'
35
12
57
'@

$gender = @'
Male
Female
Male
'@
$myNames = $name.Split("`n").Trim()
$myAges = $age.Split("`n").Trim()
$myGenders = $gender.Split("`n").Trim()

$myArray = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mynames.count; $i++)
{ 
    $myObj = "" | select Name,Age,Gender
    $myObj.Name = $myNames[$i]
    $myObj.Age = $myAges[$i]
    $myobj.Gender = $myGenders[$i]

    $myArray += $myObj

}
$myArray
```